# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb8bf50b3c0' (Swift/Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sigabrt

I am trying to learn a new language (Swift/Xcode) and I don't seem too be able to run the following example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var test: UIBarButtonItem!

    func processTimer(){
        print("a second has passed")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var timer = Timer()    // Create timer object    
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1,
                                     target: self,
                                     selector: Selector("processTimer"),
                                     userInfo: nil,
                                     repeats: true)
    }
}
```

I am getting:

> Thread 1 :signal SIGABRT ????

Comment: Welcome on the Stack Overflow! I think your question is unclear, such questions will be closed and then deleted. Please edit it, people don't know your problem, and they don't understand your abbreviations. But they are good in swift/xcode. Please give them their round sentences.

Comment: Don't use `Selector("...")`, use `#selector(processTimer)`.  This will make it obvious that the issue is that you need to define your method as `@objc processTimer() {`

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't forget to ask a question next time. I think you should change your code into:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var test: UIBarButtonItem!

    @objc func processTimer(){
        print("a second has passed")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var timer = Timer()    // Create timer object    
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1,
                                     target: self,
                                     selector: Selector(processTimer),
                                     userInfo: nil,
                                     repeats: true)
    }
}
```

And then everything should work.

Comment: OK Thank you very much. I am new to SO and Swift. I find it difficult to use Swift and all the different controls available along with getting the code done to do what I want it to do. Even with following tutorials, I find there are too many settings everywhere and it puts the programmer's mind in many places at once. Thanks anyways I will try it out for a few more weeks and see ….

Comment: Hi ross, no worries. If the answer was correct, can you then please check the answer as solving your problem?